# Sum of elements from list1 corresponding to list2

Tags: python, list

I had the following lists with the same number of random values, i.e., 10:

```
a = ['74.93', '50.91', '74.66', '125.10', '98.72', '131.63', '26.46', '76.17', '100.68', '92.5']

b =  [ '23.',  '62.',  '68.',  '50.',  '77.',  '43.',  '76.',  '79.',  '70.',  '32.']
```

I have then use a condition which gives me the list of values of a < a_cut.

For instance, if I input `a_cut = 60`.

The output  =  `[ '50.91',  '26.46']`
Which in turns corresponds to the indices 1 and 6 in list a.

So I would like to know how can I do a **summation for the values in list b which corresponds to the index in list a**.

e.g. In the case of `a_cut = 60`,

I need to get:

Output =  62. + 76. = 138.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the elements are strings? Are they guaranteed to contain the string representation of a `float`?

Comment: **So I would like to know how can I do a summation for the values in list `b` which corresponds to the index in list `a`**: Well find the indices that satisfy the condition and get the corresponding item from `b` using that index. Not sure what's so complicated about this. ...and 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
sum(float(y) for x, y in zip(a, b) if float(x) < 60)
```

Result:

```
138.0
```

The idea is iterate `a` and `b` simultaneously with `zip`. Then you check for the correct values of `a` while you summing on the values of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy` to do this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,4,3,10])
b = np.array([1,1,1,1])
a_cut = 5

np.sum(b[a < a_cut])
```

Or python's built-in `zip` function:

```
a = [1,4,3,10]
b = [1,1,1,1]
a_cut = 5
sum(el[1] for el in zip(a, b) if el[0] < a_cut)
```

Or then python's built-in `filter` function:

```
a = [1,4,3,10]
b = [1,1,1,1]
a_cut = 5
sum(filter(lambda i: a[i] < a_cut, xrange(len(b))))
```

Or use a good old `for` loop:

```
a = [1,4,3,10]
b = [1,1,1,1]
a_cut = 5
sum = 0
for i in xrange(len(b)):
    if a[i] < a_cut:
        sum += b[i]
```

Many ways will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

could use list comprehension

```
a_cut = 60

a = ['74.93', '50.91', '74.66', '125.10', '98.72', '131.63', '26.46', '76.17', '100.68', '92.5']

b =  [ '23.',  '62.',  '68.',  '50.',  '77.',  '43.',  '76.',  '79.',  '70.',  '32.']
print sum( [float(b[i]) for i,n in enumerate(a) if float(n)<=float(a_cut)])
```

**output:**

```
138.0
```